# Mass Retrieving Envelopes SOAP API Error

Tags: soap, docusignapi, envelope

When using the SOAP API, anytime I call FilteredEnvelopeStatuses to try and retrieve approximately 200+ envelopes I keep getting an exception: "The UserID did not identify a User in the systems". I am using a production account. I seem to be at a loss as to what the message means when it comes to retrieving the envelope, since as long as I keep the number of retrieved envelopes below the stated number the code works fine, What do I need to do to exceed or better yet if possible remove this limit when calling such method or others like it?

Comment: Please post your request that you're sending (strip out envelope IDs and other PII), so we can see what you're trying.

Comment: FilteredEnvelopeStatuses envelopeStatuses = client.RequestStatusesWithDocumentFields(filter); -- The filter would contain the array that holds all the 200+ Envelope Id.

Comment: What endpoint? There's currently a known bug with 3.0/api.asmx, whereas 3.0/dsapi.asmx works.